# How can I pull the data from oracle database and display with Bootstrap(dataTable)

Tags: oracle, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I want to use the Bootstrap datatable to pull the data from oracle Db and display.
I am able to display the hard coded data in HTML using Bootstrap dataTable, but I dont I have idea how to pull the data from Oracle database and display with Bootstrap(dataTable). I searched lot on Google but did not get any useful resource I have checked on official Bootstrap site, but I am not getting it.
Can any one have idea how to do that.
Please help me with this.

Comment: I guess you mean jQuery dataTables - see this -> https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_oracle

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks, I have seen lot but mos of the example are given in PHP but I am using JSP. can provide me link for that or you can explain me little bit how to do with jsp

Comment: https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp